# Odoo Missing Error while running a cron job for sending scheduled mail

Tags: python, cron, odoo, scheduler, odoo-8

I have the following code. When the scheduler runs I am getting the error message. Some one help me to resolve the error in the code

> MissingError
>       One of the documents you are trying to access has been deleted, please try again after refreshing.

```
def send_followup_mail(self, cr, uid, context=None):
        quot_ids=self.search(cr, uid, [('state','=','amend_quote')])
        for quot_id in quot_ids:
            if quot_id:
                quot_obj=self.browse(cr, uid, quot_id ,context=context)
                quotation_since=quot_obj.quotation_since
                for email_template_line in quot_obj.temp_tag_id.crm_campaign_id.email_template_ids:
                    if quotation_since==email_template_line.delay_days:
                        mail_pool = self.pool.get('mail.mail')
                        mail_id = self.pool.get('email.template').send_mail(cr, uid, email_template_line.id, 1, force_send=True, context=context)

                        if email_template_line.send_mail_to=='to_client':
                            mail_pool.write(cr, uid, mail_id, {'email_to':quot_obj.email_from}, context=context)

                        elif email_template_line.send_mail_to=='to_sale_rep':
                            mail_pool.write(cr, uid, mail_id, {'email_to':quot_obj.sale_rep_id.email}, context=context)

                        if mail_id:
                            mail_pool.send(cr, uid, mail_id, context=context)
                self.write(cr, uid, quot_id,{'quotation_since':quotation_since+1}, context=None)
        return True
```

Comment: Is that all you get from Odoo as Error Message? Seems that some record you're trying to use in that part of code, isn't in db anymore.

Comment: I am facing the error with this line  --   mail_id = self.pool.get('email.template').send_mail(cr, uid, email_template_line.id, 1, force_send=True, context=context)

Comment: That parameter `1` tells Odoo to use record with ID 1 of the model defined in the template to use for value expressions. Seems that there is no record with ID 1 of that specific model in database. Why is that parameter set to 1 anyways? Shouldn't it be `quot_id`?

Comment: I have changed like this. Its works fine now. -- sale_id=self.pool.get('sale.order').search(cr, uid, [], limit=1, context=context)
                        mail_id = template_pool.send_mail(cr, uid, template_id, sale_id[0], force_send=True, context=context)

Comment: Many thanks @ CZoellner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the modified code and works fine

```
def send_followup_mail(self, cr, uid, context=None):
            quot_ids=self.search(cr, uid, [('state','=','amend_quote')])
            for quot_id in quot_ids:
                if quot_id:
                    quot_obj=self.browse(cr, uid, quot_id ,context=context)
                    quotation_since=quot_obj.quotation_since
                    for email_template_line in quot_obj.temp_tag_id.crm_campaign_id.email_template_ids:
                        if quotation_since==email_template_line.delay_days:
                            mail_pool = self.pool.get('mail.mail')
                            template_id = email_template_line.id
                            template_pool = self.pool.get('email.template')
                            sale_id=self.pool.get('sale.order').search(cr, uid, [], limit=1, context=context)
                            mail_id = template_pool.send_mail(cr, uid, template_id, sale_id[0], force_send=True, context=context)

                            if email_template_line.send_mail_to=='to_client':
                                mail_pool.write(cr, uid, mail_id, {'email_to':quot_obj.email_from}, context=context)

                            elif email_template_line.send_mail_to=='to_sale_rep':
                                mail_pool.write(cr, uid, mail_id, {'email_to':quot_obj.sale_rep_id.email}, context=context)

                            if mail_id:
                                mail_pool.send(cr, uid, mail_id, context=context)
                    self.write(cr, uid, quot_id,{'quotation_since':quotation_since+1}, context=None)
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all write code using **new api**.

For getting template use `obj = self.env.ref('template_record_id')` then send `obj.send_mail(model.obj.id, force_send=True)`, if you want to set mail then before send `obj.email_to = 'test@example.com'`

Final code:

Somewhere in xml:

```
    <record id="email_template_record_id" model="email.template">
        <field name="name">Name</field>
        <field name="email_from">noreply@example.com</field>
        <field name="subject">Subject</field>
        <field name="email_to">False</field>
        <field name="auto_delete" eval="True"/>
        <field name="model_id" ref="model_model_name"/>
        <field name="body_html">
            <![CDATA[
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                    <title>Custom title</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>Dear Sir,</p>
                    <p>Text body.</p>
                    <p>This is automated mail, don't reply.</p>
                </body>
            </html>
            ]]>
        </field>
    </record>
```

in python code:

```
    template = self.env.ref('email_template_record_id')
    template.email_to = some_obj.obj_related_field.email
    try:
        template.send_mail(ombject_id, force_send=True)
    except Exception:
        _logger.error("Custom Error Message")
    template.email_to = False
```

Comment: I support your intention on using the new api, but why should you set template.email_to on every call? That will change the template record in database. Odoo's email templates support placeholder/value expressions. The email should be get from the record the template is used for.

Comment: I had only that working solution for now. Thanks for corrections anyway

Comment: @CZoellner I've question, My solutions is sending email immediately, and send_email doesn't has argument for email, it takes it from template, that's why I'm assigning email to it. But in above example it's adding mail to pool, and does its performance is better then this?

Comment: Sending emails by template means to use a database record from the model defined in template (or better: the template is assigned to a model). You have to give a RecordSet (an actual object) of that model as parameter for send_mail(), and this will be used to fill value expressions within the template. The template email fields (email_from, cc, ...) can be used with such value expressions. Your code persists the email on this template on every use, that's of course not that bad for performance, but just not necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I've searched on odoo modules and found good examples