# Is their any complete documentation about sending email with Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, email, odoo

I'm trying to send mails from Odoo. What I want to do is create a button, which will create a different QWeb Report for every res.partner society in my database and will send them to it. (e.g. I have 70 Society, i'd like each of them to get a personnal email sent, with a personnal report.)

I'm not asking someone to give me the solution since their is a lot of work to do if we go into the details, but I can't find any documentation about sending e-mail from Odoo. Is their at least one with the simpliest exemple of what you could do, or a better one that shows the option we have with it? (I mean from the python and xml side).

I found some people giving good answers to specifics question on forums, but none explain what each option does and I couldn't find any documentation. If you have some to give, I'm thankful.

EDIT: I'm currently looking into the source code of the basic addon "email_template" and find some interresting options but I don't really know how to trigger it, what function should be redefined, how to call it..

Comment: Odoo source code is our documentation, stop searching in internet, of course internet is easy and because of that next time search on google and if first five result doesn't meet your requirement go directly to odoo source and search there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583288/odoo-missing-error-while-running-a-cron-job-for-sending-scheduled-mail

Comment: What do you mean by personal email? Do you mean the email content, or just the design? Odoo's email templates allow you to do some cool stuff. And that is the big problem: i don't know a real good doc for the email templates, so try to figure  how to do it by studying Odoo's template examples.

Comment: Dachi -> As you can see in the edit posted before your comment, I'm currently reading the source code of some modules, the problem is I'm not experimented enougth to understand what each lines implies for the Odoo's Kernel.

Comment: CZoellner -> I mean a personnal email content and a personnal QWeb report attached. It's not really the problem since I found some teamplates exemples for this (with the '${object.foo}' notation) but to adapt it to a button press and my specific case, instead using a sheduler. So how do you do without docs when the examples are not enought? You're reading the source code? Did you read the Kernel or just the module's source is enought?